# why react user input type text make number get NaN

Tags: reactjs, regex, textbox, user-input, nan

I am learning and try to make use of user input (textbox) type text to type in number and which will auto add commas and fixed to 2 decimal places using regex. It's work at first, but when I click the same textbox again (to edit the input) then I click other textbox or outside of the same textbox, the value change to NaN. Can anyone help me on this? Below is my code:

```
<InputForm
  inputtype="text"
  name="initialBalance"
  placeholder=""
  value={props.values.initialBalance}
  onChange={async (name,value) => {
  props.setFieldValue(name, value);
                    
  }}
  onBlur={event => {

  const formatted = props.values['initialBalance'];

  var deciFormatted = Number(formatted).toFixed(2);

  props.setFieldValue('initialBalance',deciFormatted?deciFormatted.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') :Number.parseFloat(0).toFixed(2));

  props.handleBlur(event);

  }}
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
      if (/[^0-9.]|(?<=\..*)\./.test(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      }
    }}
  className={props.errors.initialBalance && props.touched.initialBalance && "is-invalid"}
  disabled={props.disabledForm}
  isInvalid={!!props.errors.initialBalance}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have found the solution to the problem. I just add below method:

```
Number.isNaN(value)
```

which will change NaN to previous input that user type in. So, the code will be like this:

```
onBlur={event => {
  const formatted = props.values['initialBalance'];

  var deciFormatted = Number(formatted).toFixed(2);

  var newValue = (isNaN(deciFormatted) ? formatted : deciFormatted);

  props.setFieldValue('initialBalance',deciFormatted?deciFormatted.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') :Number.parseFloat(0).toFixed(2));

  props.handleBlur(event);
```